# How to copy a tree where each node has more that two leaves?

Tags: javafx, treeview

I would like to copy a TreeItem in javafx.

Each node of the tree has more than two leaves. I would like to copy the whole tree. I need a deep copy of that tree. Please help me. Thank you

I am working with TreeView and TreeItem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using this pattern:

```
class Item {
    //....
}

TreeItem<Item> deepcopy(TreeItem<Item> item) {
    TreeItem<Item> copy = new TreeItem<Item>(item.getValue());
    for (TreeItem<Item> child : item.getChildren()) {
        copy.getChildren().add(deepcopy(child));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot and you saved me a lot of time. Thank you