# Update items on TreeView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to update my `TreeItem`'s from `TreeView`.

The custom `root` element, where will be download other elements:

```
public class FilePathTreeItem extends TreeItem<Path> {
private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;
private boolean isLeaf;

public boolean isDirectory() {
    return Files.isDirectory(getValue());
}

public FilePathTreeItem(Path f) {
    super(f);
}

@Override
public ObservableList<TreeItem<Path>> getChildren() {
    if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
        isFirstTimeChildren = false;

        super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren());
    }
    return super.getChildren();
}

@Override
public boolean isLeaf() {
    if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
        isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
        isLeaf = Files.exists(getValue()) && !Files.isDirectory(getValue());
    }
    return isLeaf;
}

private ObservableList<TreeItem<Path>> buildChildren() {
    if (Files.isDirectory(getValue())) {
        try {
            return Files.list(getValue())
                    .map(FilePathTreeItem::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
        }
    }

    return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
}
}
```

I saw also this solution: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5174074
It is what is necessary, but after update the `TreeView`, I want be able to save `isExpended()` property. Otherwise, all folders are closed.

I tried to use additional variable to store previous `TreeItem`'s and calculate there and new `TreeItem`. But I have identical additional variable, because it's immutable. I tried different types of `Cloning`, but nothing come out (`Gson`, `Apache`, `native cloning`, `deep cloning` from github).

I spend many times to find solutions, but did not find the ideal.

Also, I tried `refresh` method, but it's straightforward works and don't update `TreeView` with a new external files.

Comment: I found this solution for cloning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998262/how-to-copy-a-tree-where-each-node-has-more-that-two-leaves

Comment: beware (unrelated): don't overwrite isLeaf to return anything different from leafProperty().get() .. even though the doc example does is .. you'll introduce an inconsistency. see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089811